# Typesafe Config overriding values from external file

Tags: scala, configuration, config, app-config, typesafe-config

I have all my configuration set into application.conf which locates under src/main/resources. and it works fine when I run my app in production mode.

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
```

In some certain situation when I run my app in docker container and I need to override about 30 of properties.

When I add

`-Dconfig.file="/etc/deployed.conf"`

it excludes all original properties which contains "application.conf" and are not overriden in "deployed.conf".

Is there any way to solve this issue?

**Update:** Will

```
val myCfg =  ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("etc/deployed.conf"))
val config = ConfigFactory.load().withFallback(myCfg)
```

override values in application.conf and will not throw any exception if this file does not exist?

Comment: maybe add .withFallback

Comment: Have you tried renaming `deployed.conf` to `application.conf` just to see if there's a convention issue? Also, I'd set the `-Dconfig.trace=loads` flag and monitor stderr to see if there any resolution issues.

Comment: @Roby see my update

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I renamed external config as you suggested and added trace, it looks application.conf is ignored. it goes to external conf and then to reference.conf inside akka jars.

Comment: It actually parses your external conf?

Comment: Yep. Only external conf.

Comment: You are doing it in reverse. You want the override config to fallback to the default config. As for the exception why not just check if the file exists first?

Comment: @danny.lesnik do start your deployed.conf with  `include "application.conf"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you create it [manually](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/environment-aware-configuration-with-typesafe-config) you can use the withFallback method.

```
Config appConfig = ConfigFactory.parseResources(configs.remove(0));
for (String resource : configs) {
    appConfig = appConfig.withFallback(ConfigFactory.parseResources(resource));
}
```